# How to read and understand the connections/traces in a schematic?

Tags: schematics, diagram, block-diagram

I am in the process of rebuilding a dell laptop XX327 battery pack. I have removed the outer plastic from the 18650 3S2P battery pack. I plan on replacing all six cells, reprogramming the smart battery board after spot welding new cells to the board to reset the total mAh and cycle counter for the board.

I came across a [great youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Urs0xgfHKpY) where the author does exactly what I am attempting to do. He ends up building two distinct adapters to interface with the contact pins on the battery pack.  I have begun to assemble the adapter to interface with my battery pack, however, I don't understand his schematic and, I am not the best at reading and understanding schematics in general.

He shares two different schematics (shown below) for the adapter boards, one is large and one is small. I've begun to assemble/solder the larger of the two boards (also shown below).

However, I am confused about how he wires up the resistors and diodes to the outermost terminal blocks on the prototype board. In the small schematic, it looks like 4 LEDs are wired to the 4 outermost contact points/terminal blocks whereas on the large schematic it looks like the LEDs are wired to the 2 outermost terminal blocks, thus my confusion and my posting of this question.

I hope somebody can help me understand the wiring of this adapter board. Also, if there is something I am leaving out, please let me know and I will update my question.

### The Schematic

[image]

### Soldered Board

[image]

Comment: please add the actual schematic to your post, not a link to the schematic

Answer (score 1):

> in the smaller schematic of the two examples it looks like 4 LEDs are wired to the 4 outermost contact points/terminal blocks, whereas the larger of the schematics it looks he is only wiring the leds to the 2 outermost terminal blocks,

I think it's the same. You use the outermost two pins on each end to the LEDs. It looks like they are used to determine orientation.

The schematic shows eight 2-terminal blocks, but, in fact, the connector uses only four of these blocks.

From this photo:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fp0pIWwX9a6WacLTchN7sXZhBA1a78BR/view

I've extracted this close-up:

[image]

Note that both connectors have eight terminals/sockets corresponding to the eight blades of the battery connector. There is one screw terminal/socket for each blade.

Comment: wow thank you for posting pictures and adding your answer. looking at that bottom screengrab of the larger connector it looks he stuck a little wire to bridge the outer two connections of the outside terminal blocks.